# How can I connect DNS server to two networks in CISCO?

Tags: networking, dns, cisco-packet-tracer

I'm trying to connect the DNS server to two networks named Network A and Network B, I added a screenshot of my Networks. I'm not sure about the DNS server's addresses. What should be the addresses of DNS server in IP configuration?

I've searched about this on Web, but I could not find an answer to my question. Thanks in advance for your help.[here is the network schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A01PR.jpg)

Comment: Why do you think it _has_ to be connected directly to both networks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "regular" way would be to put the DNS server into either one of the subnets and setup the appropriate routes on the router (the server will get an IP within the subnet it's connected to). Alternatively you can use two interfaces on the server, this way you could connect the server to both subnets at the same time (each interface will get an IP from the subnet it's connected to).